# Is there any downside to playing solo?

Tags: dragons-crown

*Dragon's Crown* is a sidescrolling beat-em-up. The later part of the game revolves around doing alternate versions of earlier stages, many of these are more challenging and some contain (from what I recall) timed parts. If I just play solo, will I be at any significant disadvantage?

Comment: I somehow resisted the temptation to title this "Is there any downside to playing with myself?" - I hope everyone appreciates how hard that was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a prior note, all of this answer refers to offline multiplayer - I don't actually know how loot works in online multiplayer.

The main disadvantage of being solo is not the lack of other people, but if anything it's the lack of role performances that other classes might offer. Every class has strong solo-capability but each class also can bring some things that other classes just don't have. So for example, Wizard has the extremely useful Slow spell, which makes certain fights extremely more of a breeze to deal with - playing as a (not-Wizard) solo character would lose you this option. Certain classes are almost designed to work with each other, on top of special interactions like how a Sorceress's Create Food spell can give extra supplemental benefits to Elves, Dwarves, and animating spellcasters.

But as mentioned, every class is designed, for the most part, to be able to perform and clear the game alone. It may take a lot of extra work for some classes to deal with certain foes, but it's ultimately possible.

The other disadvantage, though the relevance of it depends on class, is that it limits the amount of temporary weapons you can carry around. Each player can only carry a single temporary weapon into the next room, so more people around technically allows you to bring more. There's only a handful of strategies where this is actually useful (such as a strategy I use involving a Sorceress, an Elf, and two torches for the Forest route B boss), but it's something to consider. It's a lot more relevant when you have a Sorceress with Create Food to produce plenty of temporary weapons, I suppose.

---

On the flip side, there are advantages to playing alone. Enemy health scales based on the number of people in the party, so there's less HP to deal with when you're solo. As a result of this, some of the timed portions can be easier when it's a pure damage race and you happen to actually do proper damage. Basically, this is the main balance to help make it so that things are still doable in solo.

Another bit is that loot is biased towards the classes in the party. If you're just a Fighter, you'll see swords, shields, gauntlets, and belts drop more than anything else (amulets are universal so everyone gets a healthy amount of those). Add an Amazon into the mix, and you'll see polearms, bracelets, boots, and earrings also drop more frequently. Off-class equipment can still drop, just not nearly as much. So by playing solo you can be sure that nice stuff that drops is likely to be stuff usable to your current class.

Certain post-game element below that this affects as well.

> In the Tower of Mirages, the specially enchanted equipment that drops from those foes clad in black smoke is guaranteed to be equippable to a class in the current party. It's random who it might be for, but still it's always going to be usable by someone present. This is largely just an extension of the previous point about loot, but since it's guaranteed it's a major point.